# Creating a function which returns a class type

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to create a function which has the type of a class `Node` and takes in a `Node` as a parameter.
Currently I have this, which isn't working;

```
Node return_node (Node inNode)
{
    return inNode.print_values();
}
```

I've declared some Nodes above this, but can't work out how to utilise this function, I'm also not sure you can even make a function which takes the type as a class?
I want to be able to make a function which takes the type of a class I have declared.

The print_values() function looks like this;

```
void print_values()
{
    cout << "A: " << A << "\nB: " << B;
}
```

Comment: Does print_values return Node?

Comment: It just prints the values of the node to the console.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do, and what exactly `print_values()` does, and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @LiamMet, what you write (`cout << ...`) is not _return_, it is just _print_. I suggest you read on functions in C++.

Comment: @Petr my function in this example is trying to just take the input of a given node and print it's values using print_values

Comment: @LiamMet, why does it return `Node` then, not `void`?

Comment: @Petr My function? I want a Node's values to be returned to me, if it was void, would I return anything?

Comment: @LiamMet you just set you want the function to print values, now you say you want it to return values - make up your mind ...  also, `return_node` is a bad name for a function whose purpose is to print values

Comment: But atm you are returning the return value of print_values() which is void, so atm your function isnt returning anytrhing when it is supposed to return a Node, thats an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "a node's value"? if it's an int for example your function should return an int, and should look like `return A.getValue()`.

Comment: you could write `inNode.print_values(); return inNode;` . That is a pointless waste of time though, compared to returning `void`. You could make your function both accept and return `const Node&` however that is unconventional and would lead to unclear code if you actually use that functionality.

Comment: @Brahim I meant the values inside the Node, the strings and int's associated with it. It's the function I'm having problems with as the syntax isn't working. I want to be able to change A with an input on that function.

Comment: This statement is not returning anything `return inNode.print_values();`

because `print_values()`is also not returning anything.
You will definately get an error.
Can you please be a bit more clear on your issue?

Comment: @Nishant to try and clarify my issue. It's that I want to create a function which I can use to apply to multiple different Nodes and have the function return certain properties of that Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return_node()` as of right now is a function that returns a value of class Node. Judging from what you're trying to do, you're trying to print out Node's values which could have integers, strings, etc. Whether `print_values()` is just printing out a string or returning a string, it doesn't fit the requirements of function. To clarify, return_node() needs to return something of the Node class.

If you're just trying to print out the values (print_values prints values through `cout` or `printf`), I would suggest making return_node of type `void`. However, if you're trying to do return a node, try putting `return inNode`. You'll see that there won't be an error when you try to compile it.

EDIT: just saw the edit you made. Does the `print_values()` method belong to the `Node` class?

Comment: Yes, the method does belong to the class.
In the grand scheme of things, I'm trying to use this for a much more complicated loop, but I wanted to try to give a small example instead. I want to be able to input a Node into a function, but Eclipse is saying things like "Statement has no effect 'Node'" which is why I'm curious if you can even have a function with type Node?

Comment: You can have a function with type `Node`. However, since `print_values()` is just printing out a string, `return_node()` doesn't do what it's supposed to be doing. `return_node()` needs to return a node but you're not doing that. For this particular function/idea, since `print_values()` belongs to the Node class, you can just call `inNode.print_values()` anywhere in your code as long as `inNode` has been initialized.

Comment: If I wanted to return strings and int's, would I have to write two separate functions?
I want to be able to set inNode to any Node that I have declared and then have the function perform some loops on the Node that I input. In my question I used print_values() as an example, but I presume it would have worked the same as what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you're not printing them out and actually trying to get these string and int values, then yes you would have to create two separate functions. For example: `int getNodeVal()` and `String getNodeStr`. If you want to have a new `Node` have the same properties as a preexisting `inNode`, you would have to make another method to set all the new variables or use pointers to set these new `Node` vars to your current `inNode`. For example, `Node *tmp = inNode`.

Comment: Turns out my problem was that I was declaring the function in the wrong scope, so it was nearly impossible for you guys to solve my problem. But I'll give you best answer for being the most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A class is simply a type, so the statement "a function which has the type **of a** class" doesn't really make sense. Rather you should just say "has type class".

You should think of functions in terms of the types they take as parameters (the function domain), and the returned type (the codomain). e.g. the function `int mul2(int x) { return 2 * x; }` has domain `int` and codomain `int` (i.e. `int` -> `int`).

You have *declared* the function `return_node` to have domain `Node` and codomain `Node` (i.e. `Node` -> `Node`). So does your *definition* (i.e. implementation) of `return_node` satisfy this declaration? Well, `return_node` simply returns the value returned by `print_values` which itself has implicit domain `Node` and codomain `void`. Are the codomains of `return_node` and `print_values` the same? Well no, as `Node != void`, therefore your definition of `return_node` does not satisfy the given declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to help you, because you are using the right terms in the wrong way. Lets start with the header:

"Creating a function which returns a class type"

No. You want to write a function that returns a value of class type.
Further...

"I'm trying to create a function which has the type of a class Node and takes in a Node as a parameter."

No. I guess what you mean is what you already said in the title: Return a `Node` and pass a `Node` as parameter (The type of your function is `Node TYPE_OF_YOUR_FUNCTION (Node)`, just for the record).

After clarifying this, I actually do not know what your question is. If you have a class like this:

```
struct MyClass {
    int x;
}
```

You can write a function for example like this:

```
MyClass MyMyClassFunction(MyClass a){
    a.x ++;
    return a;
}
```

In your function you arent returning anything. You declared it as returning a `Node` but you actually return the value of `inNode.print_values();` which is `void` (because this is the return type of `print_values()`). Change it to e.g.

```
Node return_node (Node inNode) {
    inNode.print_values();
    return inNode;
}
```

Comment: I apologise for my lack of terminology. I'm still quite new to all of this. You were right about your assumptions, but even after altering my code to your last piece. I'm still being told that the statement 'Node' has no effect.